# Hystrix refuses Completable Future return Type

Tags: java, completable-future, hystrix

I am trying to right a `@Hystrix` method which returns a `CompltetableFuture<String>`.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "myMethodFallback")
public CompletableFuture<String> myMethod(){
  CompletableFuture<String> future = getFuture();
  return future;
}

public CompletableFuture<String> myMethodFallback(Throwable t){
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("");
}
```

However, when the method is invoked, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.exception.FallbackDefinitionException: Incompatible return types. 
...
Hint: fallback cannot return Future if the fallback isn't command when the command is async.
```

I read somewhere that I might try altering the return type of the FallbackMethod so that it doesn't return the future, but the generic value. So I tried this:

```
public String myMethodFallback(Throwable t){
  return "";
}
```

and got this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$4 cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
```

I played around and tried add `@HystrixCommand` to the fallback method as well

```
@HystrixCommand
public CompletableFuture<String> myMethodFallback(Throwable t){
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("");
}
```

but got this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.utils.FutureDecorator cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
```

1. Does anyone have a good resource on the restrictions of a Hystrix Fallback method?
2. Is there something I can do here to make this work? Or is it just not possible to return a `Future` from a Hystrix method?

Comment: Those are some interestingly unhelpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using Spring Web reactive with HystrixCommand.

```
@Autowired
HystrixImpl hystrixImpl;

public Mono<String> getResponse() {

    return HystrixCommands.from(hystrixImpl.myMethod())
            .fallback(throwable -> {
                return hystrixImpl.myMethodFallback(throwable);
            })
            .commandName("MyCommand")
            .toFlux()
            .single();
}
```

HystrixImpl.Java

```
@Service 
public class HystrixImpl {
    public Mono<String> myMethod() {
        return Mono.just("From main method");
    }

    public Mono<String> myMethodFallback(Throwable t) {
        return Mono.just("From fallback method");
    }

}
```

We just need to use getResponse().block() to get the String value of Mono.